# How do you Specify which Columns Pandas reads in?

Tags: dataset, pandas, data

I have a huge dataset with ~470,000 rows and ~1400 columns. I only require 184 of the available columns. I'd like to limit the columns I read in to improve my dataset's loading times.

How do you specify the columns read in by a function like `pandas.read_csv()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the [`pandas` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), this can be done using the `usecols` keyword:

> **usecols: list-like or callable, optional**
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
> be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or
> strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in
> names or inferred from the document header row(s). If names are given,
> the document header row(s) are not taken into account. For example, a
> valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar',
> 'baz']. Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1,
> 0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved
> use pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for
> columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
> 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
> column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
> True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
> x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
> much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.